# Searching and capturing a character using regular expressions Python

Tags: python, regex, search, text-files

While going through one of the problems in [Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/), I am trying to solve it as follows:

Read the input in a text file with characters as follows:

```
DQheAbsaMLjTmAOKmNsLziVMenFxQdATQIjItwtyCHyeMwQTNxbbLXWZnGmDqHhXnLHfEyvzxMhSXzd
BEBaxeaPgQPttvqRvxHPEOUtIsttPDeeuGFgmDkKQcEYjuSuiGROGfYpzkQgvcCDBKrcYwHFlvPzDMEk
MyuPxvGtgSvWgrybKOnbEGhqHUXHhnyjFwSfTfaiWtAOMBZEScsOSumwPssjCPlLbLsPIGffDLpZzMKz
jarrjufhgxdrzywWosrblPRasvRUpZLaUbtDHGZQtvZOvHeVSTBHpitDllUljVvWrwvhpnVzeWVYhMPs
kMVcdeHzFZxTWocGvaKhhcnozRSbWsIEhpeNfJaRjLwWCvKfTLhuVsJczIYFPCyrOJxOPkXhVuCqCUgE
luwLBCmqPwDvUPuBRrJZhfEXHXSBvljqJVVfEGRUWRSHPeKUJCpMpIsrV.......
```

What I need is to go through this text file and pick all lower case letters that are enclosed by only three upper-case letters on each side.

The python script that I wrote to do the above is as follows:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("[a-z][A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}[a-z]")
f = open('/Users/Dev/Sometext.txt','r')
for line in f:
    result = pattern.search(line)
    if result:
       print result.groups()

 f.close()
```

The above given script, instead of returning the capture(list of lower case characters), returns all the text blocks that meets the regular expression criteria, like

```
aXCSdFGHj
vCDFeTYHa
nHJUiKJHo
.........
.........
```

Can somebody tell me what exactly I am doing wrong here? And instead of looping through the entire file, is there an alternate way to run the regular expression search on the entire file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `result.groups()` to `result.group(1)` and you will get just the single letter match.

A second problem with your code is that it will not find multiple results on one line.  So instead of using `re.search` you'll need `re.findall` or `re.finditer`.  `findall` will return strings or tuples of strings, whereas `finditer` returns match objects.

Here's where I approached the same problem:

```
import urllib
import re    

pat = re.compile('[a-z][A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}[a-z]')
print ''.join(pat.findall(urllib.urlopen(
    "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/equality.html").read()))
```

Note that `re.findall` and `re.finditer` return non-overlapping results.  So when using the above pattern with `re.findall` searching against string `'aBBBcDDDeFFFg'`, your only match will be `'c'`, but not `'e'`.  Fortunately, this Python Challenge problem contains no such such examples.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am assuming that urllib.urlopen("http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/equality.html").read() is reading the entire HTML into a string. Is there a way to break it up so that instead of reading the entire HTML in one go, we can optimize it by breaking it up into smaller chunks?

Comment: @sc_ray urllib.urlopen returns a file-like object, so you can read line by line if you prefer.

Comment: @sc_ray While reading line by line maybe more efficient, you probably won't notice the difference in speed and increased memory consumption (but of course, you should be aware of it).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using lookaround:

```
(?<=[A-Z]{3})(?<![A-Z].{3})([a-z])(?=[A-Z]{3})(?!.{3}[A-Z])
```

This will have no problem with overlapping matches.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[A-Z]{3})  # assert that there are 3 uppercase letters before the current position
(?<![A-Z].{3}) # assert that there is no uppercase letter 4 characters before the current position
([a-z])        # match a lowercase character (all characters in the example are ASCII)
(?=[A-Z]{3})   # assert that there are 3 uppercase letter after the current position
(?!.{3}[A-Z])  # assert that there is no uppercase letter 4 characters after the current position
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

with open('/Users/Dev/Sometext.txt','r') as f: 
    tokens = re.findall(r'[a-z][A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}[a-z]', f.read())

    for token ins tokens:
        print token
```

What `findall` does:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of
>   pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned
>   left-to-right, and matches are
>   returned in the order found. If one or
>   more groups are present in the
>   pattern, return a list of groups; this
>   will be a list of tuples if the
>   pattern has more than one group. Empty
>   matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of
>   another match.

Maybe the most useful function in the `re` module.

The read() function reads the whole file into on big string. This is especially useful if you need to match a regular expression against the whole file.

**Warning**: Depending on the size of the file, you may prefer iterating over the file line by line as you did in your first approach.

Comment: Method - Thanks for the response. Can you by any chance tell me what is wrong with the snippet that I provided. I am trying to learn from my mistakes here.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski - Can you elaborate on the overlapping matches and how the regular expressions do not detect such matches?

Comment: @sc_ray  I deleted my comment because it was not helpful for this Python Challenge question.  However, I was referring to the fact that `re.findall` and `re.finditer` return non-overlapping results.  In this case, `re.findall('[a-z][A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}[a-z]', 'aBBBcDDDeFFFg')` would find `'c'`, but not `'e'`.

Comment: @sc_ray  The key to Helper Method's answer is that `re.findall` returns a single string if your regular expression contains only one group.  If you had no group it would return the entire match.  If you had multiple groups, it would return a tuple of strings--one string for each group.